# hide columns dynamically in rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, rdlc

How we can hide columns dynamically  in rdlc reports in MVC 2?

Is it is possible using external parameters? How we can programmatically control the visibility of columns in rdlc reports?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't want to use the `Hidden` property, you actually want to select the column, Right Click and select `Column Visibility`. Once in here you can use an expression to set the visibility based on a parameter, something like this:

```
= iif(Parameters!column_visible.Value = 1, false, true)
```

`Hidden` doesn't work in this instance because you're not actually applying it to an object like you are when you select something like a textbox.

Comment: If you use Hidden's property expression and you have more columns at the right, the empty space will remain in between. Thanks @MrEdmundo!

Comment: @RamonAraujo, Hey did you find a way to overcome the empty space issue when you hide the columns?

Answer (score 19):

Following are the steps to hide the column

1) Add a boolean parameter with name column_visible in your report

2) Right Click on desired column and select Column Visibility.

3) Select the option "show or hide based on an expression"

4) add following formula

```
= iif(Parameters!column_visible.Value = "True", false,true)
```

5) Add following code in c# file where you are assigning value to above added parameter

```
ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[1];
if (condition)
{
   parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("column_visible", "True");
}
else
{
 parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("column_visible", "False");
}          
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: Why are you using strings, why don't just compare the booleans in the iif statement? There's no way you should need c# here.

Comment: Lightning solution.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select a column. In properties you have `Hidden`. property. Then you can set a condition, for example `=Parameters!IsColumnHidden.Value`.

If you want to do this from C# code I would send a parameter (like above) to the report saying if column should be hidden.