# Control the visibility of a table column in a Microsoft report-viewer at runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net, reportviewer

Is there a way to Control the visibility of a table column of a report created using Microsoft report-viewer  at run time dynamically. I'm using vb.net.

Comment: I think this covers the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438079/hide-columns-dynamically-in-rdlc-report

Comment: Thanks a lot but when I right click the column, there is no option called 'column visibility'. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, the resources I've looked at only talk about modifying the report during design time. So all the advice to select Visibility won't help because those options are not visible at run time. Perhaps modifying the expression property might provide a solution. Here is some information on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd354976.aspx

Comment: THanks alot. Passed a report parameter and wrote an expression for it. works perfectly. THanks again